# Searching in side an object's list of objects using lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, lambda

I have 2 tables; they have a many-to-many relationship. One is called Blog the other is Tag.

A Blog can contain a List of Tag objects. How can I go about getting all blogs that have a passed in tag name using lambda expressions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Tag table has a Name property, it might be something like this (roughly):

```
string tagName = "tag-to-search-for";
var query = Blog.Where(blog => blog.Tag.Any(tag => tag.Name == tagName));
```